# How can I send a signature request via email while using a signature via your app?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using eSignature REST API.
I used Requesting a signature via your app (embedded signing) from code example.
When the example is used, no signature request is sent by email.
Is there a way to request a signature by email while using your app (embedded signing)?

```
if("bp".equals(recipientInfo.get("usr_cls"))) {
                    signer.setClientUserId((String)recipientInfo.get("client_id"));//이 값을 넣으면 메일이 가지 않음 
                }
                //signer.setClientUserId((String)recipientInfo.get("client_id"));//이 값을 넣으면 메일이 가지 않음
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want signature by email - it's call remote signing, not embedded signing.
But the good news is - you can do that via your app/integration and using API calls just the same.
In fact - it's easier.
You just don't set the clientUserId - and that's it. The envelope would then be routed remotely via email.
Your code deosn't show the rest of it - how to create an envelope etc. I assume you know how to do that part, but if you don't - I can help.

Comment: I looked it up and found out it was easy to solve. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would you mind marking this question as answered? thanks!